# How to configure jest to fail when it takes more than x seconds

Tags: jestjs

Is there a way to fail a jest test when it exceeds x number of seconds?

There is this property: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#slowtestthreshold-number, but it's only for reporting right?

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testtimeout-number

Answer (score 3):

Global-level configuration:

- Create a `jest.config.js` file and add this [testTimeout](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testtimeout-number) option. jest will read the config file before executing.
- Add [--testTimeout](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--testtimeoutnumber) option when you are using the jest CLI like `jest --testTimeout 2000`

File-level:

Use [jest.setTimeout(timeout)](https://jestjs.io/docs/next/jest-object#jestsettimeouttimeout)

> Set the default timeout interval for tests and before/after hooks in milliseconds. This only affects the test file from which this function is called.

Test case level:

Use [test(name, fn, timeout)](https://jestjs.io/docs/next/api#testname-fn-timeout)

> The third argument (optional) is timeout (in milliseconds) for specifying how long to wait before aborting. Note: The default timeout is 5 seconds.

Comment: testTimeout doesn't work. I think that only fails the test when it's stuck for that time limit. In my case, the test is never stuck, but just the mere fact of how long it takes to bootstrap the component and how long it takes to interact within the test is taking more than x seconds